# How is this a valid Typescript expression "const s: string = ['a'][1]; "?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

When I run `const s: string = ['a'][1];` it produces `undefined` but I was expecting a type error from Typescript complier because I thought I was assigning an array to a string.

Can anyone explain how this expression is evaluated ?

Comment: I don't see you trying to "assign an array to a string" anywhere.  Wouldn't the problem be "assigning `undefined` to a string"?  Could you clarify exactly what you expected?  Because it doesn't seem to coincide with anything that could conceivably happen.

Comment: TS infers `["a"]` to have type `string[]`, which has a numeric [index signature](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). And the default TS behavior for index signatures is to assume that any property you read exists, so it thinks `["a"][1]` is `string` and does not account for the possibility of `undefined`. If you want to see `string | undefined` you can turn on the `--noUncheckedIndexedAcess` compiler option but this would affect your whole code base and make normal array indexing more annoying. Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz please post your comment as an answer

Comment: @Samathingamajig I would do so if the OP could [edit] to clarify why they thought they were "assigning an array to a string".  If the question were "why does it allow `string` instead of complaining about the possibility of `undefined`?", then I'd know how to answer.  Right now I'm mystified about the wording of the question.

Comment: @jcalz I am learning both JS & TS and found this code base on an exercises. I am not building anything yet. But up on seeing the code my expectation was, this is a type error, rather than an undefined output. Now I understand the [1] is referring to the array ['a'] second position which doesn't exist and it's return undefined.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question so that it only has one issue, then?  Since you're not asking about `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess`, maybe you should change it to `["a"][0]`, so that you actually do get a `string` both at runtime and according to the TypeScript compiler.  Then your question would be unequivocally about the meaning of `["a"][0]` and why it's not a type error.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking down your code snipped like this might make more sense:

```
const myArr: string[] = ['a'];

const s: string = myArr[1];
```

The above snipped is equivalent to the one you provided. Since `['a']` by default is a string array (`string[]`), any index you try to access will be of type `string`.

However, if you were to change your snippet to:

```
const s: string = (['a'] as const)[1];
```

You will get a few interesting type errors. Typescript now evaluates `['a']` as a this type: `type T = ['a']` which means it's a "tuple" type of length 1. So now it knows that index of 1 does not exist on the tuple. To read up more on Tuples in typescript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types

Lastly, as mentioned by @jcalz, you can enable the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` flag as a compiler option which will make the type when accessing any index on a array potentially undefined which is technically more accurate.